# ld: undefined reference to symbol 'log2@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: c, mpi, linker-errors

Whats wrong with

```
for (level = 1; level <= log2((double)size); level++)
                         ^
```

Seems like its from using `log2()` but whats wrong? I am using it with OpenMPI code actually, but commenting this line fixes things.

**[Full Source](http://pastie.org/7559178)(http://pastie.org/7559178)** see line 40

```
[jiewmeng@JM Assign3]$ mpicc -o cpi cpi.c && mpirun -np 16 cpi
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cca9x4he.o: undefined reference to symbol 'log2@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'log2@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libm.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libm.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Seems like `log2(4)` will work but I cant pass in a variable?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In in order to link `libm` you need to add `-lm` argument, as this document; [MPI under Linux in the Math Department](https://userpages.umbc.edu/~gobbert/mpi.html) says:

> If your code includes mathematical functions (like exp, cos, etc.),
>   you need to link to the mathematics library libm.so. This is done,
>   just like for serial compiling, by adding -lm to the end of your
>   compile command, that is,
>
> mpicc -o sample sample.c -lm

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that