# Compiling: //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, 64-bit, libraries, libm

I am having trouble compiling code intended for 32bit unix system on my 64bit Ubuntu, Linux. Does anyone have any ideas what may be the problem?

```
gcc main.o test.o render.o transform.o model.o vector.o color.o -o the_thing -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: transform.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cos@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The error message is telling you to add `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6` (or better yet, the short version `-lm`) to your command line...

Answer (score 6):

You should link `libm` as well when you are dealing with code that uses mathematical functions.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006145/ld-undefined-reference-to-symbol-log2glibc-2-2-5):

> If your code includes mathematical functions (like exp, cos, etc.),
>   you need to link to the mathematics library libm.so. This is done,
>   just like for serial compiling, by adding -lm to the end of your
>   compile command, that is,
>
> mpicc -o sample sample.c -lm

### **A plus**

I saw in your compile line that you are using -lSDL. SDL works with C and C++, so, if you are using pure C you should include the default math C header, which is:

`#include <math.h>`

I think that you made something like this:

`#include <cmath>`

If you are working with C++ you should not compile using the C compiler, use `g++` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your code using `-lm` argument.

`gcc file.c -lm`